# Form nesting for file upload, jQuery submitting parent form

Tags: jquery, forms, file, upload, nested

I'm trying to have the following:

```
form 1
   text input
   text input
   previewimage
   form 2
     file input, upload automatically on selecting file to hidden iframe and generate previewimage
   /form 2
   text input
   submit
/form 1
```

Basically the idea is that I have a form with a section for adding an image. However, I also want an image preview so I need a nested form to input the file. The main form should only be submitted when I hit the submit button.

I know that nested forms are not really allowed but they still seem to work. However I've run into a snag and that is jQuery submitting the main form (form 1) when it should submit form 2! It seems that since I have an AJAX form submit for form 1 that this event is fired on the form 2 onchange instead of form 2 submit like it should, even though my code says $('#form2').submit(). If form 1 is submitted normally then the problem doesn't manifest.

For modern browsers I can just cram the iframe and form 2 into the document body and start the file dialog via JS by clicking a link. But for any IE version the file input field must be present since IE doesn't seem to allow file input onchange unless the user has clicked the actual field.

One option would be to have just form 1 and temporarily change its action to form 2 action but then I have to submit the whole form and if the form is very long that slows everything down.

Is there any smarter way I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Put form2 into an iframe and bind a function to the load event of that iframe in the main document. When you submit the iframe, that function will be called in the main page and you can set the source of your preview image in the main page corresponding to the uploaded image.

Comment: Ran into problems adding anything inside the generated iframe. It seems that it would have to be done in document.ready but it seems you can't use it easily inside a jQuery plugin. Alternative solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by appending the upload form after the form where the rest of the input elements are. Then I use a link to access the file field (works in Chrome, FF and Safari). The reason why I put the form after the main form instead of just adding it to the body is that in jQuery UI modal dialog if form 2 is in body you can't access it due to the nature of the modal dialog (disables events outside the modal dialog).

In IE I put the form 2 file input into form 1 and then with the onChange event I move (append) the file input into form 2, fire submit and then move the file input back to where it was. It's a bit "hacky" but it seems to work quite nicely.